# WPF: Прозрачная форма с размытием и закруглёнными краями

Tags: c#, wpf, blur

[image]

Я хочу скруглить края прозрачной формы, которая при этом размыта.
В некоторых примерах, которые я видел, форма может быть полупрозрачной (без блюра), а края закруглёнными, но когда я использую размытие, она размывает первоначальный размер формы.
Чтобы было более понятно, я сделаю отступ в 10 пикселей, и будет видно, в чём именно проблема:

[image]

Вот код, который я использую:

```
namespace Testui
{
internal enum AccentState
{
    ACCENT_DISABLED = 0,
    ACCENT_ENABLE_GRADIENT = 1,
    ACCENT_ENABLE_TRANSPARENTGRADIENT = 2,
    ACCENT_ENABLE_BLURBEHIND = 3,
    ACCENT_INVALID_STATE = 4
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct AccentPolicy
{
    public AccentState AccentState;
    public int AccentFlags;
    public int GradientColor;
    public int AnimationId;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct WindowCompositionAttributeData
{
    public WindowCompositionAttribute Attribute;
    public IntPtr Data;
    public int SizeOfData;
}

internal enum WindowCompositionAttribute
{
    // ...
    WCA_ACCENT_POLICY = 19
    // ...
}

/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>

public partial class Main : System.Windows.Window
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    internal static extern int SetWindowCompositionAttribute(IntPtr hwnd, ref WindowCompositionAttributeData data);
    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.Close,
            new ExecutedRoutedEventHandler(delegate(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs args) { this.Close(); })));
    }

    public void DragWindow(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs args)
    {
        DragMove();
    }

    public void ButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {

    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        EnableBlur();
    }

    internal void EnableBlur()
    {
        var windowHelper = new WindowInteropHelper(this);

        var accent = new AccentPolicy
        {
            AccentState = AccentState.ACCENT_ENABLE_BLURBEHIND
        };

        int accentStructSize = Marshal.SizeOf(accent);

        var accentPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(accentStructSize);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(accent, accentPtr, false);

        var data = new WindowCompositionAttributeData
        {
            Attribute = WindowCompositionAttribute.WCA_ACCENT_POLICY,
            SizeOfData = accentStructSize,
            Data = accentPtr
        };

        SetWindowCompositionAttribute(windowHelper.Handle, ref data);

        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(accentPtr);
    }
}
```

}

Вот xaml код:

```
<Window x:Class="Testui.Main"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Main" Height="250" Width="500"
Background="#0000"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    WindowStyle="None"
    BorderThickness="0"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    Loaded="Window_Loaded">

<Border x:Name="brder" Margin = "0" CornerRadius="15">
    <Grid>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="35" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border 
            Background="CadetBlue" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
            CornerRadius="15,15,0,0" 
            Margin="-1,0,-1,0" 
            MouseLeftButtonDown="DragWindow"/>

    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Я думаю, что проблема может быть в этой строке:

```
var windowHelper = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
```

This просто передаёт размер Window, и скругление при этом не учитывается.

P.S. Статей и ссылок на эту тему не нашёл, за исключением одной, и она есть на этом сайте (автор Kamdroid). Проблема так и не была решена, в итоге.

Comment: Данная проблема уже была решена ранее:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787966